# SWRevealViewController Error. Build Fails, but no error

Tags: ios, objective-c

First of all, let me give you a heads-up. I'm moderately familiar with XCode (5) and Objective-C.

But, consider me a noob and please help me out.

I'm trying to build an app. I need a Slide out menu in all Views of the app.

I made a dummy project using SwRevealViewController Class. And I have made two slide out menus also. And it works.

I tried to use the same method in the App that I'm building.

But my build has failed with no Errors and a single warning, which I had in my previous dummy project....

I have already imported SwRevealViewController.h to AppDelegate.m and ViewController.m

I'm trying to use a TableViewController as slideout menu (which is empty, I haven't added any code to it yet). But the build is failing.

Edit:
" The error is as follows..

"@synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC Mode"

I'm using Core Data with my project. And I have to use webservice extensively in my App. So I have disabled ARC. "

I have also tried replacing table with other views, but the same result. Now I'm stuck.

I know its some thing with my code, but I couldn't find it.

I'm including code of AppDelegate.m and ViewController.m.

Please check it and tell me what is wrong. I'm at a loss here.

Edit:
" I cannot upload images due to Stack Overflow restrictions. So I have uploaded a screenshot of the error in tinypic. Here is the url.

http://tinypic.com/r/162vli/8 "

Thank you for all your help.

AppDelegate.h

```
//  AppDelegate.h
//  IndianBloodBank
//
//  Created by Roshith Balendran on 8/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Olympus. All rights reserved.
//


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SWRevealViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *UINV;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SWRevealViewController *splitMenu;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  IndianBloodBank
//
//  Created by Roshith Balendran on 8/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Olympus. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "HomePageViewController.h"
#import "SlideOutMenuTableViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "AboutUsViewController.h"
#import "SponsorsViewController.h"
#import "HowToDonateViewController.h"
#import "EmergencyViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize splitMenu,window,UINV;

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = window;

    HomePageViewController *HPVC = [[HomePageViewController alloc]init];

    SlideOutMenuTableViewController *SOMTVC = SOMTVC = [[SlideOutMenuTableViewController alloc]init];


    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:HPVC];
    UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:SOMTVC];

    SWRevealViewController *revealController= [[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

    revealController.delegate=self;
    revealController.rightViewController = SOMTVC;
    self.splitMenu = revealController;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitMenu;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

HomePageViewController.m

```
//
//  HomePageViewController.m
//  IndianBloodBank
//
//  Created by Roshith Balendran on 8/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Olympus. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HomePageViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "AboutUsViewController.h"
#import "SponsorsViewController.h"
#import "HowToDonateViewController.h"

@interface HomePageViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomePageViewController

@synthesize btn1SearchBlood,btn2DonateNow;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.055 green:0.055 blue:0.059 alpha:1]];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;

    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = [self revealViewController];

    [revealViewController panGestureRecognizer];
    [revealViewController tapGestureRecognizer];

    UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-icon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full and exact error/warning message(s) and point out where it happens.

Comment: There is no error...!!! The build simply fails...
I would like to put a screenshot, but I have just started..
Doesn't have the rights...

Comment: You said there was a warning. What is it?

Comment: Its in this line...
revealController.delegate=self;

In AppDelegate.m, below navigation controller initialization

Something about incompatible type assigned.. Have to go to Mac to post the exact problem...
Please wait while I reboot.

Comment: Actually, now i have rebooted my pc and now I have 16 warnings and 1 error...
All inside SWRevealViewController.m.

The error is,
@synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC Mode

Comment: Put the details in your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple, I just had to turn on ARC.

The basic requirement of SWRevealViewController Class is ARC enabled.

You cannot use this Class for slide out navigation with ARC disabled.

My bad guys. Thought I checked for errors with ARC enabled. My mistake.

So, if you encounter this error "@synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC Mode", just turn on ARC.